# handsontable is it possible to have comboboxes (dropdowns) on a row rather than a column?

Tags: handsontable

is it possible to have comboboxes (dropdowns) on a row rather than a column?

all the examples I've found talk about columns only, e.g.
http://docs.handsontable.com/0.15.0-beta6/demo-dropdown.html

I need a row of editable comboboxes instead, does anyone have any examples of how do achieve this, if it is even possible?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

@ZekeDroid pointed me in the right direction to the answer for what I actually asked.  Adding the code here so you don't have to waste time learning to do it for yourself.

function getCarData() {
        return [
        ['dog', 'dog', 'dog','dog'], ["Something", 2013, "blue", "blue"], ["Else", 2014, "yellow", "black"], ["Here", 2015, "white", "gray"]];
    }

```
var
container = document.getElementById('example1'),
    hot;

hot = new Handsontable(container, {
    data: getCarData(),
    colHeaders: ['Car', 'Year', 'Chassis color', 'Bumper color'],
    cells: function (row, col, prop) {
        var cellProperties = {};

        if (row === 0) {
            cellProperties.type = 'dropdown';
            cellProperties.source = ['yellow', 'dog', 'cat'];
        }

        return cellProperties;
    }
});
```

Comment: Can I attach/provide a dropdown only for a single cell and not for an entire column/row using this? I havent been able to do that. Would it be as simple as `if (row === 0 && col === 1) {}`?

Answer (score 1):

Yes what you want to do is use the `cells` option just like you would the `columns`. In this one you are supplied with `row,col` so you would do something like:

```
cells: function(row,col) {
    if (row == 0) {
        // checkbox logic
    }
}
```

And that should be all!

[JsFiddle with example](http://jsfiddle.net/pmth59ze/)

Comment: Thanks but I don't see how I can apply the "checkbox" logic to make the cell a combobox.  Are you able to elaborate or show a jsfiddle?

Comment: Sure, although that's a good exercise for you to do. I made it anyways but I suggest you learn to do it yourself as well since applying conditional options to cells and columns is crucial when using Handsontable

Comment: Great. Thanks the jsfiddle was helpful